# TYPO3 FrontendLogin redirect with hook in postUserLookUp not working

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am currently working on a service that hooks into postUserLookUp. Adter authenticating frontend users my felogin is set to redirect users to another page. This works perfectly as long as the hook function isn't active. When using the hook function the redirect seems to be ignored and I end up on the logout page after the service's form is finished.

Any ideas as to what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your TYPO3 Version and the code of the hook function? I can't see anything that would indicate such a behavior just from looking at the relevant [hook entry point](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7-1/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Authentication/AbstractUserAuthentication.php#L448-L456).

Comment: This is in TYPO3 7.6.15 and I am using a variation of this hook here: https://github.com/pgampe/authenticator/blob/ter/Classes/Hooks/UserAuthHook.php My guess is that the hook dies when displaying it's form and something in the original chain might not get executed anymore?

Comment: Could be. There is a lot of code going on in that link. Have you enabled debugging (install tool) to see if there are any errors?